# Split a text and put some text between them

Tags: javascript

i have a Javascript code from an extension im creating and i need to split the word im selecting in like, half for each part...
for example this is my code that i use for every page i need

```
function child1_7Search(info,tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({  
    url: "www.blablabla.com/" + info.selectionText,
  });           
}
```

but i have to split the selected code in 2. For example, my selected code is **1854BIGGER000208**, where the first four letters need to be split in half and put somewhere in the URL and the other twelve letters needs to be put in other place, but in the URL. 
the page needs to look something like this

https://www.urbano.com.ar/urbano3/wbs/cespecifica/?shi_codigo=001854&cli_codigo=BIGGER000208

where in shi_codigo adds two zeros and put the first half, and in cli_codigo puts the rest of the code.
The selected code its always the same length!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using [**.substring()** method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

```js
var code = "1854BIGGER000208";
var shi = "00" + code.substring(0, 4);
var cli = code.substring(4);

var url = "https://www.urbano.com.ar/urbano3/wbs/cespecifica/?shi_codigo=" + shi + "&cli_codigo=" + cli;

console.log(url);
```

**Note:**

- `code.substring(0, 4)` will extract the first four digits from the selection, returns `1854`.
- And `code.substring(4)` will extract the remaining characters in the selection and returns `BIGGER000208`.
- Note the use of `""` in `"00"` the two zeros are wrapped in a string
  so they can be concatenated with the `shi` code, otherwise `00+1854` will
  be evaluated as `1854`.

Answer (score 2):

you can try to concatenate parts like this..

```js
// this is your original text / code that you get
var text = "1854BIGGER000208"
// here we `slice` or take first 4 chars from it
var pret = text.slice(0,4);
// here we are taking other half of the text
var post = text.slice(4);
// and here we just concatenate them into final url part
var final = "shi_codigo" + "00" + pret + "&cli_codigo=" + post
console.log( final );
```

I guess that you will want to concatenate the first part of the `url` also and for that you can also prepend it with `+` sign as we did with all parts of the code above..

Comment: it would for sure,, I'll edit it little but it's pretty much very basic..

Answer (score -1):

Here are a number of string functions you can use in JavaScript.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

In particular, you may want to use the slice function. Syntax is as follows :

```
var l = info.selectionText.length() - 1;
var num = info.selectionText.slice(0,3);
var end = info.selectionText.slice(4, l);
```

Here, the properties being passed into the slice function are the start and stop points of where you would like to slice the string. As usual, the index starts at 0.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution using ES6 Sintax**

```
let yourString = "yourstringthatneedstobesliced";
let initial = yourString.slice(0,4);
let post = yourString.slice(4);
let char = `shi_codigo=00${initial}&cli_codigo=${post}`;
```